# MonoTouch versions

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios

I have a shipping iOS product using MonoTouch, and it is battle-tested using a specific set of Monotouch and MonoDevelop and iOS SDK versions.

I want to try the latest and greatest (MonoTouch 4.0.0 and the iOS SDK with Xcode4), but I don't want to compromise the working build environment that I have.

3 questions:

- How can I have both build environments on my machine and choose which one I want to use at any given time?
- Is there a way to verify which MonoTouch version it's using when I build in MonoDevelop?
- Is there a way to verify which compiler (gcc or LLVM) and iOS SDK it's using when I build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not currently possible, this is a very valid request.   We will discuss how we can have parallel installations of MonoTouch in place.   Sadly, I do not have a timeline for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps I may be misunderstanding the nature of your question but why not use a VM?

Comment: That's one solution but it's far from ideal. I'd be tripping over MonoTouch's licensing and I'd have to email back and forth with them and convince them to let me have more than 2 active licenses (if they even will), it'd take up more hard drive space, more install time, etc... I'd rather just be able to choose which version of things I'm using.